# Are you allowed to re-ask questions if you don't get answers?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

This is my first meta post, so I might get something wrong here, but I'll take the risk.

The question I'm asking here is about ignored questions and unanswered posts. I've asked a question regarding something most people use when online (Youtube), but, after one comment asking me to specify what browser I was using, it was ignored.

Which is why my question here is if you're allowed to ask similar questions to one that has been ignored (Like, re-asking the Youtube question, but in different words and a separate format)?

Thanks guys.

Comment: It seems you're talking about [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71915/streaming-video-fails-to-display-page). Since it hasn't been answered, instead of re-asking, why don't you edit the current one? When you edit a post, the question will be bumped to the top of active posts (but please don't abuse this). If you still insist on posting a new question, will it be different than your current question? If not, it will be closed as a duplicate (and probably downvoted, risking you into a question ban).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I read your question along this line "should I re-ask my own question that has not been answered within its first day". That is in fact strongly discouraged (with the old question still there) and would be considered trying to game the system.

See [Can I re-ask a question if it hasn't been answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/473/can-i-re-ask-a-question-if-it-hasnt-been-answered) for some suggestions how to go about unanswered questions:

- editing the question to add more detail, improve it, re-tag it, or make it more clear (implicit benefit: editing bumps the post to the first page again, be warned though to not game that feature either)
- try offering a bounty (though that is off the table if you do not have the reputation to spare)
- one answer to the above linked meta post also suggests to delete and re-ask (re-wording the question) but I don't see the benefit over editing the existing question

Comment: Thank you for telling me about this topic and defining rewording for me. The question I asked has been answered, and now I know to not "Game the system."